# Migrating from Docker to Podman

Tags: podman

We have extensive build our images using Docker and push them to Artifactory. We use OpenShift(3.9) to run these images in Containers.

We have to migrate to OpenShift 4.6 and organization has recommended to replace Docker with Podman.

Did anyone face any challenges migrating from Docker to Podman. I see that most of he Docker commands can be replaced with Podman.   My few questions are

1. Most of the examples show Buildah for Building Images, Can't we build image with Podman ?
2. Can we push Images to artifactory using Podman ?  Most of the examples show Skopeo for this

With Docker I used to Build , push and pull images to and from Artifactory, is it possible with Podman ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done a full migration from docker to podman in a production environment yet, however, I am completely committed to using podman only for my personal projects.

As of yet I have setup an alias docker = podman and have not run into any issues with using podman only.

Pulling and pushing to custom image registries is possible. I havent tried Artifactory with podman so far, but this [here](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-use-podman-with-artifactory/) and [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-a-local-image-repository-with-podman/) should help you with setting up the connection from podman to artifactory.

Regarding your first question: yes, podman can be used to build images. Just use it exactly the same as you would do for docker.

Buildah is another way to build images which is in my opinion a little more powerful than regular podman builds. However, if you were able to handle everything you needed to do so far with docker, I dont see an issue with building with podman.